# Vimeo player is not working after adding content security policy

Tags: laravel, content-security-policy

Vimeo player is working fine without content security policy but when I am added CSP in my project the vimeo player stops working and gives me error as given in screenshot. Have also added url in scrpt-src as given below.

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  https://vimeo.com https://www.gstatic.com https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js");
```

[image]

Comment: Don't see how this should be related _directly_ to CSP; are you getting any _other_ errors relating to this? (Also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: When I am added CSP code then this issue occur other wise it is working fine.

Comment: Now you are just repeating what you already said earlier. What about what I _explicitly_ asked you?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using security headers, then you have to add Permissions-Policy, like this:

```
 $response->headers->set('Permissions-Policy', 'autoplay=(self "https://player.vimeo.com"');
```